# Firefox is connecting to sites that I haven't opened

Tags: networking, firefox, security, hacking

I started playing with Wireshark and I have seen that firefox is connecting to some IPs even when I'm not connected to any site

```
lsof -i -a -p 'firefox_pid' 

COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox 2329 user   37u  IPv4 118753      0t0  TCP user-N501JW:37086->ec2-52-51-142-18.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 2329 user   39u  IPv4 129663      0t0  TCP user-N501JW:43368->server-52-85-74-162.lhr3.r.cloudfront.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 2329 user   68u  IPv4 140375      0t0  TCP user-N501JW:37680->wj-in-f189.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 2329 user   88u  IPv4 137617      0t0  TCP user-N501JW:34916->par03s13-in-f78.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 2329 user   90u  IPv4 137568      0t0  TCP user-N501JW:58404->151.101.1.69:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 2329 user   97u  IPv4 137533      0t0  TCP user-N501JW:33818->93.184.220.29:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 2329 user   98u  IPv4 114507      0t0  TCP user-N501JW:58916->ec2-54-201-82-144.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 2329 user  121u  IPv4 134757      0t0  TCP user-N501JW:36918->par21s05-in-f142.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 2329 user  124u  IPv6 137540      0t0  TCP user-N501JW:35008->xx-fbcdn6-shv-01-cdg2.fbcdn.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 2329 user  125u  IPv4 133683      0t0  TCP user-N501JW:57762->a23-217-230-180.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

How to know who is making those requests?

Comment: Do you have any add-ons installed? are you in any web page?

Comment: some AddOns in Firefox? amazonaws belongs to the Amazon Cloud (S3) where many large JavaScript is outsourced by some companies: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3

Comment: Yeah I suspected that. Is there a way to know which one is making those requests?

Comment: for example one by one deactivating them

Comment: by the way, firefox itself makes some connections to mozilla, etc when starting.

Comment: `fbcdn.net` belongs to facebook's content delivery network... if you're on a webpage with any sort of "like" button or that uses facebook for comments, that explains it. Similarly, `akamaitechnologies.com` is a content-delivery company that many major websites hire to speed up the delivery of their webpages from a network of servers strategically placed around the world for speed. Similar story with `cloudfront.net` and `amazonaws.com`. None of that looks particularly suspicious.